# I want to change the HTML coding to Ruby on rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, html

I want to change the following HTML coding to Ruby on rails

Help me for this

This is my coding

```
  <form class="form-signin">
            <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Email" required auto focus>
            <input type="password" class="form-control" placeholder="Password" required>
                <button class="btn btn-lg btn-primary btn-block" type="submit">
                Sign in</button>
            <label class="check-box pull-left">
                <input type="checkbox" value="rememberme">
                Remember me
            </label>
            <a href="#" class="pull-right need-help">Need help? </a><span class="clearfix"></span>
            </form>
```

Answer (score 0):

There is no think as HTML to ruby. 
you can convert it to HAML using [enter link description here](http://html2haml.herokuapp.com/)